# Application in the Taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, taskbar

Can you give me an example on how to put my application form in the taskbar?
 like Windows media player or Window search when minimize.

Comment: you should tell us what language you are using to build this application.

Comment: i'm using C#. i want to make it look like windows media player while on task bar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is creating an [Application Desktop Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177(VS.85).aspx) (also known as AppBar). The main function you use to register your application window as an AppBar is [`SHAppBarMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108(VS.85).aspx).

To get you started, you can look at this old [appbar example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/134206) with C++. If you want to do it in C#, there's a thread that discusses some [details on how to do it in WPF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/49698e52-1a29-4f24-8e4e-69230020c551/). I am not aware of examples of how to do it with WinForms, but a quick search on the web should bring something.

**Update:** Actually, if you want a toolbar that sits on the taskbar, you need to implement a Deskband. Here's a sample [DeskBand in C++](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/activex/article.php/c3595/) and here's a [DeskBand in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx).

That's what happens when you don't touch a topic in a while. :-)

Comment: And in Win7 there are "thumbnail toolbars."

See "Shell Developers Guide" - "Shell Extensibility" - "Extending the Desktop" on MSDN for a complete reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521672

Answer (score -1):

What this is really called is the 'System Tray' You want your app to have an icon in the windows system tray. Many languages provide this functionality.

Here are a few links:

http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/COM-Tech/shell/icons/article.php/c1335

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/systemtray.aspx

Comment: Windows Media Player and Windows Search don't add themselves to the System Tray.

Comment: What this is really called is the 'Notification Area'.

Comment: @Franci - My Windows Media is most certainly in the system tray.